# Diagram of Stack Given C Code

Tags: c, assembly, stack

What would the **Assembly Language (AVR) stack** look like, given the **C** code below.

I'm trying to understand how **C** code translates into AVR Assembly Language, and I need to be able to do the following in preparation for a programming question that could be on my exam.

```
int x; 

int foo(char a, int b) {
    int z; 
}

int main() {
    int q = foo('a',0x93); 
}
```

What would be the stack representation in AVR for the C code above?

Comment: It depends on the compiler used, and what [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) is used.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just need a rough general approach. No need for specific details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack frame of the foo function would be similar to the following:  First on come arguments, then saved frame pointer, return address then local variables.  Int is 4 bytes, so naturally the assembly would subtract 4 from esp to make room for the local variable.

Here it is visually:

```
int b     < bottom of stack, highest memory address
char a
ret address
fp
local variables < top of stack, lowest memory address
```

Comment: I'd be surprised to see an ESP register on an AVR